# Geography in ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to use bing maps, CF and SQLServer.

Is there a way to create a geography in coldfusion 9?
I need to create variables with geography type to call a stored procedure in a DB SQL Server.

I've done this in C# transforming points and polygons into geography but I've haven't found a way to do it in CF.

Is there a way?
Would you recommend me to do?

Comment: It sounds like the sort of thing that should be language agnostic.  If your geography is a .net class you might be able to write something similar as a cfc.  Both have properties and methods.

Comment: FYI - ColdFusion uses the Data Direct drivers to talk to MS SQL Server. Data Direct has yet to add support for the Geometry and Geography (and Hierarchy) datatypes introduced in SQL Server 2008. There is actually a bug filed against ColdFusion 10 where the mere presence of a column based on one of these datatypes will cause an error in `<cfquery>` (see https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3217374). You might have to resort to writing your stored procedure to accept the input as floats and then convert those to geography coordinates.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten - the OP is asking about ColdFusion 9 specifically. The bug you referenced is for ColdFusion 10 and comments there suggest that the Geography datatypes do work in ColdFusion 9. Just clarifying...

Comment: I was aware of that.  I was explaining ColdFusion's overall lack of support of geometry/geography and that it is in fact worse in ColdFusion 10+.  I think it might be a relevant piece of information for anyone else who comes to this question who is using ColdFusion 10+, and also if the OP is planning to upgrade to 10 (as I would hope they are thinking about since Adobe support for ColdFusion 9 ends later this year).

Yes, you can work with queries that include geography/geometry columns in ColdFusion 9, but ColdFusion itself doesn't know what to do with those columns.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten that's what I decided to do. I'm using the MS SQL capabilities to achieve what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to "RTFM" you, but as I think you're on a hiding to nothing here, an elaborate answer is perhaps a waste of time.

There's a section in the ColdFusion docs that covers interacting with .net: "[Using Microsoft .NET Assemblies](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-715e.html)" . And the SqlGeography class is well documented too: "[SqlGeography Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx)". So that should be enough for you to read-up and ask a more specific question if you get stuck. The answer to your question "Is there a way to create a geography in coldfusion 9" is "yes".

That said, as @CarlVonStetten points out, this will be of no help to you because you won't be able to pass your Geography object to the proc, because CFML doesn't support passing that sort of thing to the DB driver. You'll need to pass it primitive values and create your Geography object in the T-SQL.

Comment: *RE: CFML doesn't support passing that sort of thing to the DB driver.* So is it more than just a driver issue? (I cannot test it out today). The reason I ask is that I noticed one of the bug report comments mentioned that an Adobe employee suggested "downloading and trying Microsoft's free JDBC Type 4 driver instead of the DataDirect one that comes with ColdFusion." as a work around. Just curious if switching drivers is actually a viable alternative.

Comment: @Leigh I haven't had a chance to try it yet. I asked if all of the rest of CF's `<cfquery>` functionality would work properly with Microsoft's driver, and never got a satisfactory answer. I'll put it on my mental radar to test as soon as I can.

Comment: @Leigh I s'pose one might be able to pass the object without a `cfsqltype` value, or with `CF_SQL_BLOB`? Didn't think of that initially. Although I would not take any advice from Adobe team members as being accurate: they suggest all manner of stuff that won't necessarily work or makes no sense, just in an effort to make it look like they're doing work.

Comment: Adam - Yep. I tend to take those with a hefty grain of salt. Hence the question whether it is "really" an alternative ;-) You might be on to something with `cf_sql_blob`. From what I have read they are some type of `varbinary` field, so that might well do the trick. @CarlVonStetten - Okay. I don't have time for it this week, but if you do get around to it, keep us posted.

Comment: Yep, the thing is I can't install any extension on the server.